# Timed out waiting for debuggee to spawn

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Randomly, when I run in vscode a python script, I get this error message:
"Timed out waiting for debuggee to spawn"
[image]

It happens randomly, sometimes disappears when killing all vscode processes but sometimes it doesn't help.

My vscode version is:
and the debugger extension launcher is:
/homes/noyah/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.19.13251009/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons for this. You can try the following methods：

1. Right click vscode and set the administrator identity to run:

[image]

2. Check your Python version. If it is too old, this problem will occur.
3. Try using older python extensions or pre-release version：

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This exact error message can occur when the file extension is included in the module entry in vscode's launch.json.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Module",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "my_module"
        }
    ]
}
```

In other words, if your module is called `"my_module.py"`, then the entry in launch.json should be `"module": "my_module"`, rather than `"module": "my_module.py"`.

Whilst this may not be your solution, since your problem is intermittent, your post title brought me here, so it will bring others. I hope it proves useful.

Additional information:

When debugging Python under Windows, you get a helpful message in the terminal window, such as:

> c:\Program Files\Python311\python.exe: Error while finding module specification for 'my_module.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: **path** attribute not found on 'my_module' while trying to find 'my_module.py'). Try using 'my_module' instead of 'my_module.py' as the module name.

However, when debugging on a Raspberry PI with the same launch.json, you do not get a message like this in the terminal window.

This is how I fell upon this solution to the error message.